# PHP and Apache configuration in uploading data to database

Tags: php

I encountered problem in my configuration of my php because not all data was uploaded to database eventhougn my files is not large it was only KB.
my server is apache.
I already edit this:

```
•max_input_time

•memory_limit

•max_execution_time

•post_max_size
```

but still not all data was save to my database..
I tried everything and yet, nothing was change. still not all was save to my database 
Thank you

Comment: what data type is the column your attempting to store the data too? Also show your query and php

Comment: what kind of data you uploaded? image?

Comment: Oh, and in your list I can't see `upload_max_filesize`